# Is this subset a subspace of $V = \Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $\mathbb{R}^3$ has standard operations.

$W$={($x_1,x_2,1$):$x_1$ and $x_2$ are real numbers}.

I have been doing well proving subspaces but this one is slightly confusing me.

I am hoping if someone can tell me whether im approaching this correctly. My attempt is below:
[image: My attempt]

So $W$ is a subspace of $V = \mathbb{R}^3$  right?

Comment: I changed the $x_1,x_2$ to a's and b's for simplicity sake. Easier for me to read at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added two elements of $W$ you got $2$ in the third coordinate. It was supposed to be $1$. So $W$ is not  a subspace.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Also $W$ is not a subspace because it does not contain $(0,0,0)$ since $0\ne1,$

and it does not contain $r\vec u$ for $r\ne1$.

Comment: gosh thank you as well. that makes sense...

Comment: Could i have deduced it was not a subspace solely because there was no $\pmb0$=(0,0,0)?

Comment: Yes, any vector (sub)space must contain the zero vector

Answer (score 1):

It isn't closed under addition, or scalar multiplication, and it doesn't contain the zero vector.   So $W$ isn't a subspace (on three counts).